# MVC 3 to MVC 4 Razor Compiler Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am getting a runtime error, saying that I am missing a closing paren. The error occurs on the line where I set emailText

This code works in MVC 3 but not MVC 4. I know the new Razor is more strict but syntactically this code still looks right. All parens match, etc.

Any ideas?

```
 @if (Model.Counselors != null)
   {
                for (var i = 0; i < Model.Counselors.Count; i++)
                {
                    string counselorDivId = "counselorname" + i.ToString();
                    string deleteLink = "<a class=\"icon delete counselor\" data-attr-divid=\"" + @counselorDivId + "\" data-attr-id=" + @Model.Counselors[i].Id + " style=\"float:right;\"></a>";
                    string emailText = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactEmail) ? (Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactEmail.Length < 29 ? Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactEmail : "Email " + Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactName) : "");
                }
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to see the generated view code (the path to generated view .cs is included in exception detail). As for your problem - I'd try to switch to classical if (...) {} instead of ? operator.

Comment: Have you tried removing one line at a time to see when the error disappears?

Comment: By removing the nested ternary, the error goes away. When I convert the ternary to classic if/else, the error comes back

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, but I guess logically, nested "@" blow up MVC 4/Razor 2. By removing the nested "@" prefixes, the code was successfully parsed and executed

```
@if (Model.Counselors != null)
       {
                    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Counselors.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string counselorDivId = "counselorname" + i.ToString();
                        string deleteLink = "<a class=\"icon delete counselor\" data-attr-divid=\"" + counselorDivId + "\" data-attr-id=" + Model.Counselors[i].Id + " style=\"float:right;\"></a>";
                        string emailText = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactEmail) ? (Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactEmail.Length < 29 ? Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactEmail : "Email " + Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactName) : "");
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    @(if (Model.Counselors != null)
       {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.Counselors.Count; i++)
            {
                string counselorDivId = "counselorname" + i.ToString();
                string deleteLink = "<a class=\"icon delete counselor\" data-attr-divid=\"" + @counselorDivId + "\" data-attr-id=" + @Model.Counselors[i].Id + " style=\"float:right;\"></a>";
                string emailText = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactEmail) ? (Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactEmail.Length < 29 ? Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactEmail : "Email " + Model.Counselors[i].CounselorContactName) : "");
            }
})
```

Comment: Weird. Actually the fix involved removing the nested "@" prefixes

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with the last line that starts with "string emailText ...".  For some reason razor does not like the less than sign in your ternary statement.  When I switched it around to be a greater than sign, then it looks like it worked.  I am not sure if this is a bug in razor or not.